# Removing fabric from unity altering AndroidManifest

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-manifest, google-fabric

When taking out fabric from a unity build I could not find any resources on the website, there were only iOS and Android. I took out all file out. What do I need to do to the android manifest to make sure it is out of there too?

Comment: Nothing to do the Manifest. Just remove any file/folder you didn't add to your project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove fabric files from

Assets/Fabric

Assets/Plugin/Android

Assets/Plugin/IOS

Android manifest are merged with the plugins, so if you removed them the manifest will not have any fabric resources